# Unable start sqldeveloper in UBUNTU 14.04

Tags: java, oracle, ubuntu, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am on ubuntu 14.04 with java 1.6. I want to run the sqldeveloper.sh to start the sqldeveloper.

when I run the command `./sqldeveloper.sh` the command prompt ask for java home directory full path
when I give `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre/bin/java`.
I get `Error: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre/bin/java/bin/java not found` it clearly says that ubuntu unanable to locate the java home directory.

but i have check using command `echo $JAVA_HOME` and it returns /usr/lib`/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre/bin/java/bin/java`

to check whether I was correct or not, I followed this

Here is the output of exact location when i trace my java location

```js
varun@mycom:~$ whereis java

java: /usr/bin/java /usr/bin/X11/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz

varun@mycom:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/java

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Aug  7 11:21 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java

varun@mycom:~$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/java

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Aug  7 11:21 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre/bin/java
```

How do I resolve this? please help

Comment: Your `JAVA_HOME` should be `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya your JAVA_HOME should be `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/` and it should worked